# Is it possible to create a private but persistent file?

Tags: java, android

As asked before, I'd like to know if it's possible to create a persistent private file, that won't be deleted if the app is uninstalled.

I tried saving a file with the openFileOutput() method using Context.MODE_PRIVATE, but these files are deleted when the app is uninstalled.

What I'd like is to get a private and protected file, accessible only by my application but kept if the app is uninstalled

Thank you for your help

Comment: it's your uninstall that deletes files, so if you don't add those files to your uninstall, it won't delete it. You are very vague, and this is somewhout off scope for SO

Comment: @Stultuske , I edited my question, can you explain me how can I specify the files to be deleted when the app is uninstalled ?

Comment: What you could do is encrypt the file so that only your programm is capable of accessing it. This won't stop other apps/the user from fiddling with the file or entirely removing it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to know if it's possible to create a persistent private file, that won't be deleted if the app is uninstalled.

If it is possible to do this, then Android is broken.  Fundamentally, the Android device is owned by the user.  Leaving stuff on the user's device after your app is uninstalled is bad enough.  Doing it in a way that prevents the user getting rid of it is (frankly) a breach of the user's trust.

Such a feature (if it existed) would be open to abuse.  Consider this:

1. I am an evil person.
2. I write an application that will stealthily drop large undeletable files on the user's device.
3. After filling up the users device, my app helpfully makes an "offer" to the user to delete the files ... for payment of "a small recovery fee".
4. If the user uninstalls my app, they still can't delete the files.
5. When they reinstall the app, the fee is increased ...

(Even if the user is technically able to find and delete the files, it is still pretty obnoxious behavior for an app to do this.  Bear in mind that a lot of users won't know how to find and delete the files to get their storage space back.)

---

If you want to protect your content files, then *don't* leave them on the user's device after your app is uninstalled.   Or if you do, then use encryption ... and give the user the option of vetoing this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported for ordinary apps on ordinary devices. Apps running on rooted devices may have more options here.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm working on terminal for clients, I cannot root them

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to use external storage and save a private file there that will remain on the device even after the app is uninstalled then no, you can't do it.

See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#PrivateFiles) and in particular the following

> Files that rightfully belong to your app and will be deleted when the user uninstalls your app. Although these files are technically accessible by the user and other apps because they are on the external storage, they don't provide value to the user outside of your app.

The only similar solution I can think of is to save the file as public on external storage and add an empty `.nomedia` file in the external files dir. This prevents the media scanner from reading the files. Also from the above documentation link:

> This prevents media scanner from reading your media files and providing them to other apps through the MediaStore content provider.

Comment: And it isn't possible into the internal storage, to make it persistent ?

Comment: Can you not rethink your design? Why does it have to work against the api?